# Wireless packet loss

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I experience ~10% packet loss when running wireless.
What it means to me is an average torrent download speed at 50% my wired speed (because of time out the speed goes to max, drops down, goes to max again etc..).
When playing online games, I get lag spikes once every 2 minutes lasting 20 seconds.

The setup I use:
Net gear r6300 router
Laptop running ubuntu 14.04 with intel ac7260 lan card

For testing, i have my laptop in the same room (2 meters from the router) and got the following result:  65 packets transmitted, 57 received, 12% packet loss, time 64077ms.

I tried 1000 packets from a windows machine with 10% loss. When using cable there is no problems.

Do anyone got some clue what could cause this?

Edit: Forgot some info and made some more testing
Running the router with DD-WRT does NOT solve the problem.
Running 100 packets through 2,5 ghz produce 0% packet loss.

Comment: Relevant: [What would cause really sporadic packet loss, when signal strength is fine](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/1880)

Comment: 10% packet loss is a serious problem. You should do some testing with other devices first to determine where the problem is located.

Comment: Yes, it is pretty damn annoying! I tried my own pc, and a friends pc running windows. I am testing on a third pc right now, which shows me the same error. The packets timeout after 10 packets on the first two pc's i tested with (9 good packets 1 bad, 9 good again 1 bad). I have the same router setup at another location with no problems at all.

Comment: Is the packet loss to your router or some internet destination?

Comment: I am pinging the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more testing, I belive the router have a hardware fault in the 5 ghz part. After running a longer ping test (view stats below) on the 2.5ghz net, the loss was 0% and the ping not more than 350 ms max.

I downloaded a 3,84 gb file via torrent, and saw a similar download curve as with wire.

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
452 packets transmitted, 452 received, 0% packet loss, time 451630ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.071/11.026/347.302/32.123 ms